# No such file of directory error when attempting "bundle exec jekyll serve"

Tags: jekyll

Had a Jekyll running fine 3 days ago. Today its failing and I suspect it due to a system update on my Windows machine. Problem is, I can't figure out how to troubleshoot this. I get the error below when attempting to run "Jekyll serve", even though I've been able to verify the location of the file..

I've tried removing and re-cloning the repository several times and in multiple root path locations. This despite the fact that this worked 3 days ago. So any pointers on where to look for the root cause would be appreciated.

E, [2015-02-22T13:01:45.263372 #8332] ERROR -- : Actor crashed!
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - C:/Users/brestin.... insert long path here .../node_modules        C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-2.7.11/lib/listen/record.rb:113:in `open'
        C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-2.7.11/lib/listen/record.rb:113:in`entries'
        C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-2.7.11/lib/listen/record.rb:113:in `_fast_build'
        C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-2.7.11/lib/listen/record.rb:65:in`block in build'
        C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-2.7.11/lib/listen/record.rb:64:in `each'
        C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-2.7.11/lib/listen/record.rb:64:in`build'
        C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:26:in `public_send'
        C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:26:in`dispatch'
        C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:63:in `dispatch'
        C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/cell.rb:60:in`block in invoke'
        C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/cell.rb:71:in `block in task'
        C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:357:in`block in task'
        C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/tasks.rb:57:in `block in initialize'
        C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/tasks/task_fiber.rb:15:in`block in create'
jekyll 2.4.0 | Error:  No such file or directory - C:/Users/brestin.... insert long path here .../node_modules

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `exclude: [node_modules]` to your configuration file.

Comment: that didn't fix it, but is on the right track. "node_modules" is already in the existing _config.yml file, so the issue appears that that it isn't being honored. Any idea what could be causing that?

Comment: And using that, I've temporarily removed the node_modules folder and at least I can debug again.I'd still to get to the root of this, but this at least unblocks me. Thanks @parkr. :)